# Gradually learning the keybindings provided by AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex

If I do `M-x forward-char`, Emacs gives a very useful message

```
You can run the command "forward-char" with C-f.
```

Considering the fact that Emacs can find all LaTeX keybindings in the file `latex.el` under `LaTeX-math-default` provided by AUCTeX, 
is it possible that in LaTeX mode (AUCTeX) Emacs recalls me the Keybindings?
For example after typing `\sigma` Emacs shows a message that

```
You can insert "\sigma" by `s .
```

This would be very useful as it permits to gradually learn the keybindings in LaTeX mode.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the menubar should show the keyboard shortcuts if they are defined.  And, the same thing is available with a popup-menu (which shows the shortcuts) -- e.g., `(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-3] 'mouse-popup-menubar)`.  That way, you don't have messages ad nauseam.

Comment: @lawlist I was going to comment that the math mode symbols aren't in the menu, but they actually have a whole menu of their own! Even the ones that don't have a defined short cut are shown, with the code needed to produce them. Very handy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modifying my answer from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/detection-of-a-latex-math-syntax-error-at-emacs-level/7707?noredirect=1#comment12153_7707) we can just pull this data out of `LaTeX-math-default`, which is a list of 4-tuples

```
(CHARACTER MACRO MENU UNICODE)
```

where `CHARACTER` is the character used to bind it (I know it looks like an integer, but it's a character, use `(string CHARACTER)` to see), `MACRO` is the Latex macro without the slash, `MENU` is the name for the menus and `UNICODE` is a unicode character used for display in the menu.  We want to check the first and second elements:

```
(defun show-latex-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((sym (symbol-at-point))
         (latex-symbol (TeX-member sym LaTeX-math-default
                                   (lambda (a b)
                                     (string= a (nth 1 b)))))
         (shortcut (nth 0 latex-symbol))
         )
    (if (and latex-symbol shortcut)
        (message "You can insert \\%s with `%s"
                 (nth 1 latex-symbol)
                 (key-description (string shortcut))))))
```

There are probably better ways to continually show the output, but one way to use `post-command-hook` to run the above function after every command.  We'll use an if to make sure this only runs in `latex-mode`

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (bound-and-true-p LaTeX-math-mode)
                (show-latex-symbol-at-point)
              )
            ))
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Your code works. After typing $\sigma$, a message appears telling `You can insert \sigma with s`. Let me report a possible bug, if I type $\oplus$m there is an error telling `Error in post-command-hook ((lambda nil (if (eq major-mode (quote latex-mode)) (show-latex-symbol-at-point)))): (wrong-type-argument characterp nil)`. I think this is caused by the fact that `auctex` has not set a shortcut for `oplus` (`oplus` can be found under `LaTeX-math-default`). And from this error on, the code seems to not working, e.g. by typing $\sigma$ nothing happens.

Comment: @Name I fixed it to not try to print when `CHARACTER` is `nil`

Comment: Perfect. Few minor suggestions: 
(1) I think the message `You can insert \sigma with \`s` is better than `You can insert sigma with s`.
(2) Currently after typing `\rightarrow` the message `You can insert rightarrow with ^F` appears. I think the message `You can insert \rightarrow with \`C-f` is perhaps better.

Comment: And, fixed again.